# unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList and HashMap

Tags: java, json-simple

I have the following function that uses org.json.simple to create JSON object.

```
public JSONObject createJSONRequest() {
    // /* Create JSON Objects */
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, mAccessToken);            
    map.put(SESSION_ID_KEY, mSessionId);
    map.put(SNAPZ_ID_KEY, mSnapzId);
    map.put(EMAIL_KEY, mEmail);
    map.put(EMAIL_PWD_KEY, mEmailPwd);

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.add(map);
    jsonObject.put("parameters", list);
    jsonObject.put("function", "verifyEmail");

    return jsonObject;
}
```

However, I keep getting this warning when I use lint checker.

```
[unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList
        list.add(map);
                ^
where E is a type-variable: E extends Object declared in class ArrayList

 warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type HashMap
        jsonObject.put("parameters", list);
                      ^
where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class HashMap
    V extends Object declared in class HashMap

warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type HashMap
        jsonObject.put("function", "verifyEmail");
```

I have tried to use the generic type. HashMap uses generics, but the other objects `JSONObject` `JSONArray` don't.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: From where is JSONArray, JSONObject?

Comment: A guess: See https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java and https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/issues/detail?id=84 (this means that you can *not* avoid these warnings, except for by suppressing them...)

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks. - And it would have been so easy to write `class JSONArray<E> extends ArrayList<E> {`.

Comment: @ant2009 If this is from the json-simple library (as I assume), then you might consider adding the `json-simple` tag (and I can turn the comment into an answer...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are getting this warning because the library uses raw type collections internally.
To hide this warning you annotate your method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

If you want to use json library with generics support. You can go for [Google GSOn](https://github.com/google/gson). I have used it myself in many projects. It is easy and uses generic collections.

Comment: so the answer "never use `com.googlecode.json-simple`" cause who is going to annotate everything in the code?